# SQLite rawquery

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting an error with a rawquery on Eclipse on a DB in the assets directory. The DB is 'pre-loaded' with tables and data and the SQL string, first comment line, works in SQLite DB browser. When I copy the SQL string to code and modify to remove quotes it errors. The code below is from the 'standard' public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{ .I am new to android/java and would appreciate any assistance or suggestions.

```
        public Cursor getAllSectionDescriptions( String DBtable, String source){
    //Works in DB: SELECT  "Description" FROM  "SectionProps"  WHERE   Source = "UK"        
    //String q = "SELECT  Description FROM  SectionProps  WHERE   Source = UK " ; <= errors in code
    String q = "SELECT  Description FROM " + DBtable + "  WHERE   Source = " + source + " "; //<== errors in code
    //06-24 16:53:03.373: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1000): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: SectionProps: , while compiling: SELECT  Description FROM  SectionProps  WHERE   Source = UK 

    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(q, null);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    return mCursor;

}//end cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to put double quotes around your object names. So you'll want to do this:

```
String q = "SELECT  \"Description\" FROM \"" + DBtable + "\"  WHERE   Source = \"" + source + "\" ";
```

Note the double quotes preceded by the escape character '\'

Answer (score 0):

To execute queries, there are two methods: Execute db.rawQuery method Execute db.query method To execute a raw query to retrieve all departments:

```
Cursor getAllDepts()
  {
   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+colDeptID+" as _id, 
        "+colDeptName+" from "+deptTable,new String [] {});

   return cur;
  }
```

The rawQuery method has two parameters: String query: The select statement String[] selection args: The arguments if a WHERE clause is included in the select statement Notes The result of a query is returned in Cursor object. In a select statement if the primary key column (the id column) of the table has a name other than _id, then you have to use an alias in the form SELECT [Column Name] as _id cause the Cursor object always expects that the primary key column has the name _id or it will throw an exception .